# spring batch multithreaded patitioning slow performance when inserting data in BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION

Tags: spring-batch

When we run our POC for spring batch partitioning, it is taking almost 5 min to insert 1700 rows in table BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION. Does spring batch can be configured to insert it in batch instead of single insert at a time?

Comment: What version of Spring Batch are you using?  This should have been addressed via https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-1908

Comment: I am using spring batch 3.0.3 release.